# Proxy External API request in PHP from Edit.js in Block Plugin

Tags: block-editor, rest-api, wp-remote-get

I'm working with a third-party API that has optional filters on their API. I'm creating a block where the user has two select elements in Edit.js that are displayed on the backend of the block. They can select filters, specialty, and location, these values are then stored in attributes.

Once a user changes a select, I want to fire off a PHP request using these attributes passed to the PHP function that uses `wp_remote_get()` to build the proxy and dump the data into the rest point.

I have the Edit.js function setup but am unsure how to call the PHP function from the Edit.js file with the passed block attributes.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "proxy" here a little bit? You mention "building the proxy and dumping the data into the REST point" whenever a used changes the `<select>`s in the Block Editor, but I really have no idea what you mean by that. Or maybe simplify your question down to "how to call a PHP function (or is it a WordPress REST API endpoint?) when a Block Editor input changes?"

Comment: Thanks for the reply @bosco! So proxy is meaning take an external API call and calling it WP server-side to get around CORS and (WordPress acts as the middleware) so the public doesn't see the external API URL as well. 

Anyways, I figured it out! I created a rest API with the route `'ih/v1', 'jobs(?:/(?P<state>\d+))?(?:/(?P<speciality>\d+))?'` which has two optional paramters. 

Then the block edit function fires to that Rest URL and depending on the parameters, it builds a fetch URL and hits the external API, and dumps it into the internal WP API

I'll have a repo up soon.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out!

First, I created a rest endpoint in PHP.

https://github.com/bbuilds/ih-top-nurses-block/blob/main/inc/rest.php#L11

The rest point has optional parameters using regex and then in the `register_rest_route()` callback builds a fetch URL depending on the parameters passed to the WP-REST endpoint.

It then fires to the external API `wp_remote_get($fetch_url)` and dumps the data into the REST endpoint.

https://github.com/bbuilds/ih-top-nurses-block/blob/main/src/edit.js#L77

Then in my block edit function, I set up the internal rest API call using `apiFetch from "@wordpress/api-fetch"` using a similar buildFetch API.

Full repo: https://github.com/bbuilds/ih-top-nurses-block